# Como gerar fragments automaticamente?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Olá, Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde o usuário criará perguntas no backend, e eu terei que receber elas através de uma API, gerando-as uma por tela no android. O que eu preciso saber é se eu consigo criar fragments dinamicamente, uma vez que cada usuário pode gerar números diferentes de questões, e como eu faço isso? E eu consigo fazer o botão de passagem de tela funcionar junto com fragment?
No momento eu estou fazendo de uma forma onde eu crio framelayouts e deixo como GONE, no momento eu que eu clico na seta a direita ele troca a questão, dando GONE na anterior e VISIBLE na próxima, será que não tem alguma anim que faça essa mesma função do fragment ?. 
[image: Esse é o print da tela onde eu quero que aconteça essa função]

Comment: Esse problema, ao meu ver, envolve lógica de programação.
Você pode apenas "instanciar" as perguntas a cada vez que ele passa o botão "próxima" e criar uma animação que cause a ilusão que o fragment pulou para o lado, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, estou fazendo mais ou menos isso, só que além de passar pelo botão, eu também tenho que fazer arrastar com dedo, como a movimentação de um fragment

Comment: Para passar pro lado você vai ter que usar uma coisa chamada ViewPager (paginador) e "dentro dele" vai precisar de um adaptador de fragmentos (FragmentPagerAdapter).
O FragmentPagerAdapter vai ter de size o número de perguntas que estiver numa lista...(na verdade o size é encontrado automaticamente no momento em que voce passa a lista pro adaptador).